# Chrome headless file download with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-headless

In headless mode, Chrome defaults to disallowing file downloads.

However, recently they added an option to DevTools to enable this behavior:

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior

Using Selenium with ChromeDriver in Python, how do I allow file downloads?

Comment: Please check with the chromedriver team if they have added that option. Because chromedriver controls these options and we won't know until we ask chromedriver team about it

Answer (score 1):

Here's the chromedriver ticket to add support for headless file downloads: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1973

> File downloading is disabled when using current version of headless
>   Chrome (#60). Support to enable downloading is added to version # 62,
>   which is currently in Dev channel. Need ChromeDriver to support this
>   feature too.

It also references https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481 which has reproduction steps for the issue:

> Chrome Version       : Chromium 58.0.3023.0
>
> What steps will reproduce the problem? (1) Set headless mode
>   (--headless) on command-line (2) Point URL to downloadable file (3)
>   Nothing happens
>
> What is the expected result?
>
> When launching in headless mode and pointing to an URL with a
>   downloadable file, file should be downloaded and saved in "Downloads"
>   folder.
>
> What happens instead?
>
> Nothing happens, file doesn't get downloaded.