# Download files via selenium headless chrome on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So the issue of downloading files via headless chrome with selenium still seems to be a problem as it was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135302/chrome-headless-file-download-with-selenium-in-python) with no answer over a month ago.  but I don't understand how they are implementing the js which is in the bug thread. Is there an option I can add or a current fix for this? The original bug page located [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481)
All of my stuff is up to date as of today 10/22/17

In python:

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {"download.default_directory": "C:/Stuff", 
         "download.prompt_for_download": False,
         "download.directory_upgrade": True, 
         "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
         }

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/aaron/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = options)

# test file to download which doesn't work
driver.get('http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip')
```

If the headless option is removed this works no problem.

The actual files I'm attempting to download are PDFs located at .aspx URLs. I'm downloading them by doing a .click() and it works great except not with the headless version. The hrefs are javascript do_postback scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you locate the anchor href and then use get request to download the file. This way it will work in headless mode and will be much faster. I have done that in C#.

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                #f.flush() commented by recommendation from J.F.Sebastian
    return local_filename
```

Comment: I'm trying to download pdfs and the hrefs are actually javascript do_postback scripts. The link generated when viewing the pdfs are all idencital .aspx urls.

Answer (score 1):

I believe now that Chromium supports this [feature](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481) (as you linked to the bug ticket), it falls to the chromedriver team to add support for the feature. There is an open ticket [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1973), but it does not appear to have a high priority at the moment. Please, everyone who needs this feature, go give it a +1!

Answer (score 0):

For those of you not on the chromium ticket linked above or haven't found a solution. This is working for me. Chrome is updated to v65 and chromedriver/selenium are both up to date as of 4/16/18.

```
    prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': False,
             'download.directory_upgrade': True,
             'safebrowsing.enabled': False,
             'safebrowsing.disable_download_protection': True}

    
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    driver.desired_capabilities['browserName'] = 'ur mum'
    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'C:\chickenbutt'}}
    driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

If you're getting a Failed-file path too long error when downloading make sure that the downloadpath does't have a trailing space or slash\or backslash. The path must also use backslashes only. I have no idea why.